# SQL Dynamic Conditional Masking manipulating HAVING clause

Tags: oracle, jdbc, dynamic, masking

I have been tasked with a requirement that falls under dynamic masking.
Where this differs from most dynamic masking requirements is that the resulting SQL must mask using a HAVING clause instead of a WHERE clause.  At least this is what I have come to learn.

Specifically:
Several rules must be accommodated but I am using two for pilot development and research.  They are:

1. Any aggregate that contains values from less than 3 companies cannot be shown.
2. Any aggregate that contains contribution to total greater than 95% from any given company cannot be shown
3. Must accommodate all systems retrieving data from this database.  Examples would be a MicroStrategy v10 platform and a custom platform submitting standard queries (to simply show the wide disparity of platforms making requests)

Ideally I would show the rows of data but only mask the values in the sensitive columns.  However, given my current findings, I will accept filtering the rows.

**Environment**

- Oracle 11g Fusion
- Strategic vision is to move to something other than Oracle, such as Hadoop

Again, there are more rules but lets start with those.
If I consider a simple query like this: (sample data at end of this post)

```
select
    Time_Wk, Category, Brand, sum( Value_Sales )
from
    clientData
group by
    Time_Wk, Category, Brand
```

I would need to apply the masking rules above and alter the SQL to include a HAVING clause which would result in the following SQL

```
select
   Time_Wk, Category, Brand, sum( Value_Sales )
from
   clientData
group by
   Time_Wk, Category, Brand
having
    count( distinct Retailer ) > 2
    and ( sum( Sensitive_Sales ) / sum( Value_Sales * 1.0 ) ) < .95
```

This certainly doesn't take into account more complex queries with joins or those already with HAVING clauses.  Baby steps.

Here is what I have considered thus far and my findings:

1. Oracle VPD

   - This was promising until I realized I must implement a HAVING clause.  To date I have not been able to find anything that indicates manipulating the HAVING clause will work.  Working on a setup that will allow me to test.
   - Can anyone confirm one way or another I can manipulate the HAVING clause with Oracle VPD?
2. Oracle API's

   - I read about API user hooks but it seems these are only available in Oracle HRMS.
   - Does anyone know if Oracle API hooks are accessible in a non-HRMS installation?
3. JDBC

   - Thinking of having code within a JDBC driver that will parse out the SQL statement and manipulate the HAVING clause accordingly.
   - This will also require additional queries into the database to get parameters (possibly only at startup, will consider that in design)
   - Not familiar with JDBC code and actively researching it.
   - Can anyone confirm this is possible?
   - Any code examples I can reference?
4. 3rd Party Solutions

   - I am currently looking at [Hexatier](http://www.hexatier.com/).  Although based on initial discussions with their team, I'm not optimistic.  I have a demo coming up to consider these very requirements.
   - Any suggestions of other 3rd party solutions to look into?

Thank you in advance for taking a look at this post and for any information you might be able to provide.  It would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Data if you are really interested in playing with this scenario

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clientData;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientData(
   Time_wk         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Category        VARCHAR(4)
  ,Brand           VARCHAR(5)
  ,Retailer        VARCHAR(8)
  ,Value_Sales     INTEGER 
  ,Senstivity_Flag INTEGER 
  ,Sensitive_Sales INTEGER 
  ,PRIMARY KEY(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer)
);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Coke','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Coke','NonSens5',200,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Coke','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Coke','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Coke','NonSens6',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens1',25,1,25);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (1,'Cola','Pepsi','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (2,'Cola','Coke','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (2,'Cola','Coke','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (2,'Cola','Coke','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (2,'Cola','Pepsi','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (2,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (2,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Coke','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Coke','Nonsens4',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Coke','Nonsens5',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Coke','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Coke','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Pepsi','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (3,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (4,'Cola','Coke','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (4,'Cola','Coke','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (4,'Cola','Coke','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (4,'Cola','Pepsi','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (4,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens1',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (4,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (5,'Cola','Coke','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (5,'Cola','Coke','Sens1',0,1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (5,'Cola','Coke','Sens2',0,1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (5,'Cola','Pepsi','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (5,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens2',100,1,100);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (6,'Cola','Coke','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (6,'Cola','Pepsi','NonSens3',100,-1,0);
INSERT INTO clientData(Time_wk,Category,Brand,Retailer,Value_Sales,Senstivity_Flag,Sensitive_Sales) VALUES (6,'Cola','Pepsi','Sens2',100,1,100);
```

Comment: Does this need to be done dynamically?  Could you instead provide a data mart with pre-aggregated data (at some reasonable grain) that is deemed to be safe and let your tools run queries and do other aggregations on top of that?  None of the options you list would strike me as particularly reasonable.  Writing your own JDBC driver would seem like the approach most likely to work but that would be a non-trivial amount of effort because you'd be writing the entire driver from scratch plus you'd have to figure out how to manipulate arbitrary SQL statements (which won't always be possible).

Comment: Justin - thank you for the quick response.  We are in fact trying to move away from the pre-aggregated / pre-masked data.  The problem is that it over-masks as it cannot quite possibly consider every combination of characteristics.  i also agree with your assessment of the JDBC driver not being trivial which is why I am so aggressively double and triple checking the other options.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but for a JDBC solution, there's also [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy), which allows intercepting and modifying queries and their parameters.

Comment: Mick - In short, I'm trying to mask values based on conditions which require either a HAVING clause being added to the query or additional sub-queries.  I will look into the datasource-proxy you suggested.  Thank you.